# ERROR : TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable and json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, flask, scikit-learn

I'm trying to deploy my ML model using Flask.But i am getting the above error.
The code below is a Random Forest Classifier on the iris data set.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

### Loading the dataset

```
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

### Spliting the dataset

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y , 
random_state = 1)
```

### Building the model

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=2)
```

### Training the classifier

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

### Predicting the Species

```
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
print(predicted)
```

### Checking the accuracy

```
print(accuracy_score(predicted, y_test))

import pickle as pickle
pickle.dump(clf,open("rfc.pkl","wb"))
my_rfc = pickle.load(open("rfc.pkl","rb"))

import requests
import json

url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
data=json.dumps({'sl':5.5,'sw':3.2,'pl':3.7,'pw':1.2})
r=requests.post(url,data)

print (r.json())
```

### The Flask code :

```
import numpy as np 
from flask import Flask
from flask import abort
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
import pickle as pickle

my_rfc = pickle.load(open("rfc.pkl","rb"))

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Iris prediction"

@app.route('/api',methods=['POST'])

def make_predict():

 data=request.get_json(force=True)
 data_request = [[data['sl'],data['sw'],data['pl'],data['pw']]]
 data_request = np.array(data_request).reshape(1,4)
 y_hat=my_rfc.predict(data_request)
 output=[y_hat[0]]
 return jsonify(results=output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port=8000,debug=True)
```

**error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "new1.py", line 40, in
>    print (r.json()) File
>   "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py",
>   line 896, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) File
>   "/home/saurabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py", line 354, in
>   loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/home/ line 357, in
>   raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from
>   None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
>   (char 0)

Comment: in which line are you getting error?

Answer (score 1):

In case the JSON decoding fails, `r.json()` raises an exception. For example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response contains invalid JSON, attempting `r.json()` raises ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

It should be noted that the success of the call to `r.json()` does not indicate the success of the response. Some servers may return a JSON object in a failed response (e.g. error details with HTTP 500). Such JSON will be decoded and returned. To check that a request is successful, use `r.raise_for_status()` or check `r.status_code` is what you expect.

so check your status code if it is 200 then it should parse the json
if it is 204 then there is a problem with URL. 
check it using

```
print(r.status_code)
```

for more info [refer this link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: i got the status code as 500

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error
Usually happens on programming errors or if the server is overloaded. A terribly good idea is to have a nice page there, because your application will fail sooner or later